# pg-promise doesn't delete but doesn't throw error either

Tags: node.js, psql, pg-promise

I have the following query which successfully delete records when I run it in the psql shell:

```
delete from schedule_set USING schedule, event WHERE (schedule.schedule_set_id = schedule_set.id) and (schedule_set.id = ${id}) and (select count(*) from event where (complete IS TRUE)) = 0 RETURNING *
```

I'm generating the query with a JS function - that's why I have ${id} in the query, than call the following:

```
    return db.any(schedule.deleteSchedulesByScheduleSetId(params), params)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

When I have a syntax error in the query I get an error - this tells me that the query is being ran against the database. When I fix the syntax I don't get any errors but nothing is deleted either.

Any ideas why or how to debug? - thanks

Comment: So your `WHERE` results in deleting nothing. But it is still a successful operation. Why do you expect method [any](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#any) to return an error? It's not supposed to. If you want that query to return an error, you should use method [many](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#many).

Comment: but it is supposed to delete somethings. When I replace ${id} with a number and run the same query in the psql shell, it deletes 4 records as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Method [any](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#any), as documented, only rejects when executing the query results in an error. If your `DELETE` query doesn't delete anything, it is not an error.

If you want your `DELETE` query to result in an error when it doesn't delete anything, you can use `RETURNING *` in the end of the query, and execute it either with [many](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#many) or [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one), depending on how many records it is expected to delete (and thus return) normally.

The most practical approach however is not to use any of the above, because returning deleted rows is an extra operation, typically useless. Instead, you should rely on the number of rows actually deleted, and then act accordingly.

For that you would you use method [result](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#result), converting the output into the number of rows affected (deleted in your case):

```
db.result(query, values, a => a.rowCount)
    .then(count => {
        // count = number of rows deleted
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    })
```

Comment: I believe there's a misunderstanding here. I'm not expecting it to throw an error. I'm expecting this query to delete 1 record. Reason I said it's not throwing an error is to emphasize there's nothing the database complains about so I don't know where to look. I make a call to my api to delete this record, and the record is not deleted - if I go to the terminal shell where I'm running psql and run the same query with replacing ${id} with a number than it deletes the record. The query seems not to work when i send it with pg-promise. Do I make sense?

Comment: I actually find your example with the db.result and replaced any with that i while ago because  i need to return a different status code when nothing is deleted.

Comment: @melis must be a mistake in your query formatting. Most typical is passing in a string for `${id}` instead of an integer. Use [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) to see what is really being executed, or at the very least, log event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query).

Comment: thanks for pointing at the init options. I printed my query right before the execution. My api responded with `no record is deleted`. I checked the database - they were not deleted. I copy pasted the logged query to terminal window and ran it: the record is deleted. That's the problem. I believe if that was a permission issue I'd get an error. I'm out of ideas what might be happening.

Comment: could be something wrong with the query or connection, like going to the wrong schema/database. I don't know, I cannot diagnose it from here, you will have to do it yourself ;)